# How to populate a dropdownList, using Entity Framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, drop-down-menu

Hi I want to show a dropdownlist in the Create, Edit pages using the Entity framework 5 MVC.

The dropdown list will be populated with from a Powershell script result parse to a string, something like this exmaple (no MVC):

Default.aspx

```
var shell = PowerShell.Create();
shell.Commands.AddScript("(Get-AzureLocation).DisplayName")
Collection<PSObject> results = shell.Invoke();

foreach (var psObject in results)
{
 droplist.Items.Add(psObject.BaseObject.ToString());
}
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="droplist" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />
```

I want to recreate that but with ASP MVC Entity Framework, for one option of the create and edit forms.

Comment: And is it hard to find an example online? You could start with http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/06/bindpopulate-dropdownlist-using-entity.html

Comment: Thanks, I already did a research.

In that example the data come from a Database, but in my case the data come from a PowerShell request, actually the data is in a List, because I might store the PowerShell request output into a List.

Comment: How does EF related to it then?